# Apache Camel's Bindy with CsvRecord doesn't handle special unicode characters like ®

Tags: java, apache-camel, bindy

I'm using Apache Camel 2.17.1 to process a CSV file and I'm using Bindy in conjunction with CsvRecord to parse the file and unmarshal each line into a POJO.

The issue I'm facing is that some of the fields in the file have special unicode characters like "Blah ®" and these are not being parsed correctly -- instead, the String field will end up holding "Blah �" instead...

Is this a known bug and/or is there some workaround or configuration I can specify to enable these characters to be handled correctly as unicode characters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What encoding does the file have? Change it in Camel to match that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your input file format. Change charset to UTF-8 and try again.

Comment: it ended up being windows-1252, but you got me in the right direction! I was able to specify the charset to sftp in the same way as using the file2 component: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html -- I used the UTF-8 charset when writing these special characters to the HTTP POST body using the http4 component.